# How to display all rows in a single column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I print all the rows in the series generated?

```
isDateGreater = newDF.Effective_Date > newDF.Paid_Off_Time
print("the size of isDateGreater " + str(isDateGreater))


the size of isDateGreater 0      False
1      False
2      False
3      False
4      False
 
481    False
482    False
483    False
484    False
485    False
Length: 486, dtype: bool



Effective_Date      Paid_Off_Time
08/09/2016          25/09/2016
28/09/2016          29/09/2016
18/09/2016          1/09/2016
10/09/2016          5/09/2016
```

**EDIT Issue**
If there are 10 000 rows in the  data set, when I print out, I want to print ALL 10.000 rows, currently with the code above it prints only 9 rows.

Comment: Use `df = newDF[newDF.Effective_Date > newDF.Paid_Off_Time]`

Comment: It doesn't return a boolean series.

Comment: Not understand, what should be expected output?

Comment: As printed in the original questions, when you compare the values of 2 columns, a panda boolean series should be returned with False, True... The problem is that when I do print, I want to print ALL 486 rows

Comment: Sorry, is possible create some sample data and expected output from this sample data? Because not idea what need (and why my solution not working)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is data are not converted to datetimes, so here are compared strings.

So need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True`:

```
newDF.Effective_Date = pd.to_datetime(newDF.Effective_Date, dayfirst=True)
newDF.Paid_Off_Time= pd.to_datetime(newDF.Paid_Off_Time, dayfirst=True)
```

If need datetimes without times add [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
newDF.Effective_Date = pd.to_datetime(newDF.Effective_Date, dayfirst=True).dt.normalize()
newDF.Paid_Off_Time= pd.to_datetime(newDF.Paid_Off_Time, dayfirst=True).dt.normalize()
```

And then compare:

```
df = newDF[newDF.Effective_Date > newDF.Paid_Off_Time]
```